# How I can add null data to a result set, where it doesn't exist in the DB - without inserting new data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm wondering how I can add null data to a result set, where it doesn't exist in the DB also without needing to insert new data into DBs.

Let's say I have a table with 3 devices, a second table with 3 services and a third table containing counts of number of hits for a particular service from a particular device.

Here's the query I am using to return the hits data, followed by some example results:

```
SELECT 
d.device, s.service, r.hits
FROM results r
JOIN dt_devs d ON d.deviceID = r.deviceID
JOIN dt_serv s ON s.serviceID = s.serviceID
GROUP BY d.device, s.service, r.hits
ORDER BY d.device, s.service, r.hits

+--------+---------+------+
| Device | Service | Hits |
+--------+---------+------+
| D1     | SA      |    9 |
| D1     | SB      |    4 |
| D1     | SC      |    6 |
| D2     | SA      |    3 |
| D2     | SC      |    1 |
| D3     | SC      |    5 |
+--------+---------+------+
```

And here is the desired result set:

```
+--------+---------+------+
| Device | Service | Hits |
+--------+---------+------+
| D1     | SA      | 9    |
| D1     | SB      | 4    |
| D1     | SC      | 6    |
| D2     | SA      | 3    |
| D2     | SB      | NULL |
| D2     | SC      | 1    |
| D3     | SA      | NULL |
| D3     | SB      | NULL |
| D3     | SC      | 5    |
+--------+---------+------+
```

I think I need to try creating a temporary table with nulls on the 'hits' column that I can join to, but I can't think how to do this dynamically so that there are nulls for the various combinations of Devices and Services.

I'm limited to CTE as far as temp tables go, since this query will be run inside PHP script.

Would anyone kindly be able to give me any pointers?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN`. Also, your `GROUP BY` is useless. You're doing a `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's already been mentioned by Kermit, thought of putting the corrected query

```
SELECT 
d.device, 
s.service, 
r.hits
FROM dt_devs d
INNER JOIN dt_serv s ON d.serviceID = s.serviceID
LEFT JOIN results r ON d.deviceID = r.deviceID
```

Comment: I had to swap the joins around to get it working on my real world version, but this helped me achieve my objective. Thank you @Rahul!

Comment: @AshBestos, alright. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it really helped.